# Binary Search Tree Syntax

Tags: javascript, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

For this portion of an implementation of a binary search tree in JS, what is the significance of referring to "this._root"? (why can't they say "this.root")? The link for this is available at http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/16/computer-science-in-javascript-binary-search-tree-part-2/

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype = {

    //more code here

    remove: function(value){

        var found       = false,
            parent      = null,
            current     = this._root,
            childCount,
            replacement,
            replacementParent;

        //make sure there's a node to search
        while(!found && current){

            //if the value is less than the current node's, go left
            if (value < current.value){
                parent = current;
                current = current.left;

            //if the value is greater than the current node's, go right
            } else if (value > current.value){
                parent = current;
                current = current.right;

            //values are equal, found it!
            } else {
                found = true;
            }
        }

        //only proceed if the node was found
        if (found){
            //continue
        }

    },

    //more code here

};
```

Comment: maybe the author thought "_root" was less-likely to collide with an existing property. JSLint call this out as pointless and poor form, since it's not really private at all...

Comment: Thanks! I responded to the first answer but would also take your input: 

Is it ok for me to interpret that as - in effect I could just write "this.root" instead of "this._root" if I was just implementing a simple BST and not worried about scope issues 

Also just to be clear _root is not a separate variable from root? It is just "root" that is defined in the body of the prototype and is not accessible outside of it

Comment: i don't know the implementation details, but as long as you're consistent, you can call anything anything (with about 10-20 exceptions, "root" not being one of them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They may be trying to indicate that this variable should not be accessed outside of the object (`private` in other languages).

Python has a strong convention of using names starting with underscore character to indicate that this field or method is private. The author may be trying to apply the same convention to javascript.

Comment: Thanks - so is it ok for me to interpret that as - in effect I could just write "this.root" instead of "this._root" if I was just implementing a simple BST and not worried about scope issues

Comment: If you where writing your own, yes this is not a problem. If you where using the library linked to you need to use the name they gave it.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that more complete example is located here: https://github.com/nzakas/computer-science-in-javascript/blob/master/data-structures/binary-search-tree/binary-search-tree.js

Regarding `this._root` - I think it's author's decision only, without any special meaning.